# Could a container bind a specific network interface to reach external network?

Tags: docker

After surveying, I knew container can bind the exposed port to a specific network interface. But I think it works only for traffic which ingresses to container from external network.
I would like to assign a specific interface to a container so that the container can reach external network from the interface.
For example, I have two interface, eth0 and eth1. I want to bind a container to eht0. When executing command “ping 8.8.8.8” in a container, the traffic should reach external network from eth0 consequently.
Could it be possible and how to achieve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask for linux networking

Comment: [There is this question is on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/696747/125521)